# If $\pi$ is a permutation, how many permutation $\sigma$ can be reached from $\pi$ exchanging $r$ indices?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-proofs

This problem comes from my Master Thesis in combinatorial optimization.

Let $\pi \in \mathbf{S}_n$ be a permutation of $n$ elements and $r \in \{2,3,\dots,n\}$. Define the neihborhood $\mathbf{N}_r(\pi)$ centered at $\pi$ of radius $r$ as all the permutation that can be reached from $\pi$ exchanging $r$ indices, i.e.

$$
\mathbf{N}_r(\pi):= \Big\{\sigma \in S_n \, \bigg| \,  \# \{i \, | \,\pi(i) \neq \sigma(i) \} = r \Big\}
$$
I would like to prove that

> $$\label{1}
> \tag{1}
> \#\mathbf{N}_r(\pi) = \binom{n}{r} r! \sum_{k=2}^r
>  \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}, \qquad \text{for every $\pi \in \mathbf{S}_n$.}$$

I showed by hand that
$$
 \#\mathbf{N}_2(\pi) = \binom{n}{2} 
$$

Is there a theorical way to prove the result \ref{1}?

I think the problem can be transformed into some classic counting combinatorial problem.

Comment: Isn't it just $\binom nr\times !(n-r)$?  That is, you just the $r$ "fixed points" and then take a derangement of the remaining $n-r$ elements.

Comment: Did you mean $ \binom{n}{r} \times (n-r)!$ ?

Comment: No.  For any $k\in \mathbb N$,  $!k$ denotes the number of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the set with $k$ elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. This seems pretty easy now. Could you post it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments,

For any $r$, we build such a permutation by selecting the $r$ fixed points and then choosing a [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the others.  Thus the answer is $$\binom nr \,\times \,!(n-r)$$